# How to add custom css to the single Toast message in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, toast, toastr

### MY QUESTION :

How to add css to the single Toast used in components in Angular, as there can be multiple toast but i want to change a single toast?

Eg toast image : [example toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVeFB.jpg)

I want to add my css to the particular toast message.So, that i can **align message text in the center** i.e File Import started..

how my Angular directory looks like

```
 | app
    |
    |-components
    |    |
    |    |-test [/app.ts , /app.css]
    |
    |style.css
```

### What I Tried :

1. I added the following codes to my CSS and TS code :

**my rough app.css code**

```
.test {
   text-align : center !important // I tried without ! important also
}
```

**my rough app.ts code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.css' ]
})

export class app {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  showSuccess() { 

       // I tried \" test \" also

    this.toastr.success('<span class="test">File import started</span>', '', {

      enableHtml : true   //even I have added the messageClass : 'test' 
    });
  }
}
```

#### HOW IT WORKED BUT I DON'T WANT THESE WAYS  :

1. by putting my css code into the style.css (main global css) **(X I don't want to change my main style)**
2. by adding `::ng-deep .test instead of .test` : this is harmful it will change all my toast-dialogue.
3. by adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in @component : but this will change my  other Css.
4. by using `<center>` tag : still i don't want to do it because it will fix my issue but what if i want to add multiple css.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think ::ng-deep solution is harmful?  You can add messageClass to your toast (i.e. messageClass: 'exampleToast') and use `::ng-deep .exampleToast .test {  //write your custom css here } ` to style only your toast component.

Comment: hi @ilkengin thanks for replying and your solution worked .. I tried messageClass : 'test' and  then .test { text-align :center} it was not working and now after ng-deep it worked. I misunderstood the concept I thought that it will change my all toast styling..

Comment: @ilkengin could you put some light why and how it worked .. I will be thankful

Comment: actually yesterday i used ::ng-deep .test (my point 2) .. and what i faced was my all toast changed (maybe some syntactical mistake)..

Comment: Well, when you say `::ng-deep .test` you are styling the span with test class added (see your code). However,  messageClass adds the class to your toast message itself (not the span). Therefore, when you say ::ng-deep .exampleToast .test, it means style the element with class `test`, inside anouther element with class `exampleToast`. Also, ng-deep helps you search for every element in the DOM matching with your criteria. If you don't add ng-deep Angular only searchs for matching element in your component's html only. I hope I could help :)

Comment: thanks understood the concept ..Actually , in the above statement my all toast meaning was that my all 4 toast alignment was changed .. I haven't used the span tag when i was using messageClass ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply *titleClass* and *messageClass* when your toast is used and *overwrite* the css background-image to *align icon and text*:

```
 showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success("Hello world!", "Toastr fun!", {
      titleClass: "center",
      messageClass: "center"
    });
  }
```

Add css class in your global styles:

*Styles.css*:

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.toast-success {
  padding-left: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 35% !important;
}
```

Or use with *:ng-deep* if you want to add it in your component's styles css:

*app.component.css*

```
:ng-deep .center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Other alternative is create your own toast component extending *Toast* and use it customising its template adding a css class for centering the text.

[Using a Custom Toast](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#using-a-custom-toast)

The issue in this case is that you can't override the css background-image property to align icon and text. You can only do that in *styles.css*

[Changing default icon styles](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#faq)

Here's the **Demo**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-toastr-angular2-4pqrqw

Comment: hi @AntonioVida .. thanks for the reply, but i tried this .. see my point in how it worked section (i solved it by 4 ways)... I don't want to add my css to style.css file instead this i need to add in app.css ..is it possible?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the concept. still Is it possible? or it can't be possible because of runtime styling and toast can only read style.css(i.e is our main style file).

Comment: Hi @ADARSHKUMARCHOUDHARY, I've updated the answer and demo. It's possible if you use your own custom toast component.

Comment: hi , see the comments less code and it will work and thank you for posting the solution (your solution will also work).. just by adding a field messageClass : 'my custom class' ...  then in css file just use ::ng-deep .my custom class { add your code here}

Comment: Great. I write down this way too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the titleClass property to apply the css class on the toast message.

```
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.css' ]
})

export class app {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  showSuccess() { 
    this.toastr.success('File import started', '', {
      messageClass: 'test'// this will apply the test class to the toast title.
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: hi it's message not title .  so i used messageClass : 'test' , also i used your solution too .. but not worked.

Comment: your solution also works with messageClass .. if I use ::ng-deep .test {} in css . thanks